# Attaching policy to role not working via boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to attach AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole to a custom role. The program runs with no error, but in AWS UI I do not see the policy attached to the role. This is my code

```
iam_client = boto3.client("iam")
res = iam_client.attach_role_policy(RoleName = "dummy", PolicyArn= "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole")
print(res)
```

This is the role document:

```
{'Version': '2012-10-17', 'Statement': [{'Effect': 'Allow', 'Principal': {'Service': 'lambda.amazonaws.com'}, 'Action': 'sts:AssumeRole'}]}
```

[image]

What am missing here?

Comment: This is trust policy only. Your policy want be there. Please double check or make screenshots of your role.

Comment: Role is present. Added screenshot for the same in question

Comment: What happens when you click dummy? What is there?

Comment: Dummy will not have AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole. It comes up only after I click page refresh it comes up. Navigating to users or roles or any other pages does not work

Comment: Discovered this behaviour awhile ago, is this expected?